# Why doesn't the target attribute work in my frames?

Tags: html, frames, target

I'm building a FRAME solution for my [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system). But, before you all start showing me disrespect about the entire frame thing keep in mind that this is a solution that would be visible only to administrators, and the reason why I'm doing this in frames is because then I don't have to keep reloading the administration controls. So the 
entire *visitors-can't-bookmark* issue doesn't really apply here. Still, I'll probably look into other ways of doing this in the future (possibly with a popup).

Anyway, it's been some fifteen years since I last used frames, and for some reason my target attributes doesn't work. If you go here:

http://www.eklundh.com/admin/structure/frame.php?path=/index.php

The links in the left "pane" should open in the right pane, but doesn't. And I can't seem to understand why. What am I doing wrong?

If you have a good suggestion on how to solve this by not using frames (but still not having to reload the left pane for each page load) then I'm all ears, but I'd also like to hear about solutions to my target problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the pages in the main frame you have:

```
window.name = "mainwindow";
```

So you'd need to target `mainwindow` instead of `main`.  Or just take that code out, which seems a lot more sensible...